# Textbox and Dropdown Control - jQuery, PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I want to type for example "ABCD" in the textbox and immediately dropdown list will show the value "ABCD". Kindly help me.

Comment: Did you tried anything so far?

Comment: Show us some code what you tried so far..

Comment: read from textbox using jquery and append to select with option html tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question then you need to add `input` field value in `select list` options you can do it like below

```html
 <input name="option" type="text" id="option">
    <select id='mySelect'>
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <option value="default">default</option>
    </select>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('input').on('change', function(event) {
         var option = $('#option').val();
     if(option){
      $('#mySelect').append( '<option value="'+option+'">'+option+'</option>' );
      }
    });
    
    </script>
```

Comment: hi @user1234 thank you for your reply. I don't want to use <option></option>

Comment: @JayitaRoy if it worked then please mark it your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').on('change', function(event) {
      $("select option").filter(function() {
            //may want to use $.trim in here
            return $(this).text() == $('input').val(); 
      }).prop('selected', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's too difficult to achieve the requested result that mention in your question. I suggest you to use auto-Complete textbox jquery control to solve this problem.
For your reference kindly visit this link. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/